# Can I use libfreeradius to make own radius server?

Tags: c, freeradius, radius

I want server, that can handle two clients with **different secret behind one IP**. Freeradius cant halp me. It uses static ip-secret binding for dynamic clients.

Cant hook own module in Freeradius 2 and 3.

How I can use freeradius libs to parse raw udp packet and change Message-Authenticator? Whre is parser functions?

I want make proxy-pass like server..

Client requests with `secret1`, my proxy auth packet with secret1, copy data to new packet encrypt it with `localhost constant secret2` and send it to freeradius. Freeradius reply will be recoded and sent to client back.

Now trying to link to libradius-radius...

Comment: How would you decide, which secret to use for encrypting/decrypting passwords?

Comment: @Ctx, user-password attribute to be reencoded. Proxy know client secret and radius secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeRADIUS 4 will support dynamic binding of IP/Port tuples to secrets which effectively solves your issue.  If you wanted to build something yourself, then you could use libfreeradius, but honestly, it's meant for internal consumption by the utilities that ship with FreeRADIUS and the radiusd binary, the API (let alone the ABI) is extremely volatile and often changes between minor releases, so you may find you need to spend a lot of time maintaining whatever you come up with.

If you're set on doing this, you might find it easier to work with FreeRADIUS 4 HEAD, as the protocol parsers are split into separate independent libraries which are very easy to initialise outside of the main server.

The main functions you'd need to call are `fr_radius_init` to initialise the protocol library, and then `fr_radius_encode` to encode packets and `fr_radius_decode` to decode packets.

You'll need to come up with your own IO functions, though there are some in `src/lib/util/socket.c` that offer basic abstractions.

Comment: I want not to bind secret to IP, but to NAS-id (32).

Thanks for FreeRadius 4 tip

Comment: Ah, OK.  That might be available also.  The problem with previous versions is they didn't decode the packets (mitigation against DoS).  I think FR4 does decode the packet, so you can get at the attributes, or at least could be modified to do that if it doesn't currently, but the binding will always be on IP/Port tuples.  This generally works, even in the case of NAT traversal, because internal devices don't share external port mappings, so the src port and src IP can uniquely identify traffic from a device behind the NAT.

Comment: freeradius-server/src/lib/server/client.c - seems port not used.

Comment: Yeah it's mostly in proto_radius now, and there's a common framework for dealing with clients across protocols.  We'll clean it up soon.